# Display markers in a Google Maps Map based on the selection of a ACF taxonomy field and a ACF Google Maps field

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type `locations` containing a Google Maps field `location-gmap` and a few text fields for street, zip code, city and possible url.

Attached to the locations custom post type i've attached a custom taxonomy `thelocations`. I have created six locations, 2 locations have the term `group1` 3 locations have the term `group2` and one location has the term `group3`.

Then i've created an ACF options page containing a taxonomy field `op-contact-tax`. The taxonomy is the `thelocations` with the field type `Multi Select`.

Displaying all locations as markers in the map works without a problem based on this article:  http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/google-map/

But when i try to narrow the selection down with the aid of the taxonomy field and show only the location of the terms `group1` and `group3` a new code snippet is necessary; based on the following article http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/taxonomy/ (the basic display of multiple values). The code i use is the following:

```
<div class="acf-map">
<?php $terms = get_field('op-contact-tax');
  if( $terms ): foreach($terms as $term): 
  $location = get_field( 'location_gmap', $term ); ?>
  <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
    <p class="address"><span><?php echo the_field( 'location_street', $term ); ?></span><span><?php echo the_field( 'location_postalcode', $term ); ?></span> <span><?php echo the_field( 'location_city', $term ); ?></span></p>
    <?php $locationurl = the_field('location_url', $term);
    if(!empty($locationurl)) { ?>
       <a><?php echo $locationurl; ?></a> 
       <?php }
       endforeach; ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Problem is no markers are shown at all nor `print_r()` gives any output at all (no matter if i try to display `$terms` or `$location`). Any ideas? :/

Thanks in advance Ralf

**Update:**
Ok due @kaiser recommendation to prevent double efforts the link to the acf forum:

http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/display-markers-of-a-gm-map-based-on-the-selection-of-a-taxonomy-and-gm-field/

Comment: Ok the get_field for $terms is missing options since the `op-contact-tax` field is on a options page. But even with that applied `$terms = get_field('op-contact-tax', 'option');` there is no output. :/

Comment: Did you try it with the [Advanced Custom Fields Support Forums](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/).

Comment: Yep, tried it meanwhile, but they are more or less idle for the last few weeks, so i posted my question here first. Guess they are busy cause of the readying of acf5.

Comment: You should link to there in your question so the efforts aren't doubled on both ends.

Comment: ok i've placed an update to my initial question here with the link. thanks for the heads up!